# Display range of multiple overlapping events on Calendar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, events, calendar

I have a screen which needs to display a range of overlapping events on Calendar, for e.g if you have a booking of 1/08 to 03/08 it should display a container on these dates, overlapping a calendar, I was unable to find any plugin to complete this approach, so created a custom calendar by myself, how to display booking events on this, picture is attached for better understanding of design, it would be great if someone if someone could help on this, thanks in advance.

```
ListView.separated(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(widthSpace(viewPadding)),
            separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return SizedBox(height: heightSpace(3));
            },
            itemCount: 12,
            controller: scrollController,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int month) {
              final lastDay = DateTime(2023,month+2,0).day;
              final firstDate = DateTime(2023,month+1,1);
              return Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    CustomText(months[month],size: 2.1,weight: FontWeight.w500),
                    SizedBox(height: heightSpace(1)),
                    const CustomText("2 Discounts",size: 1.8,color: Color(greyText),underline: true),
                    SizedBox(height: heightSpace(1)),
                    Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: days.map((item) => CustomText(item,weight: FontWeight.w500,textAlign: TextAlign.center)).toList()),
                    SizedBox(height: heightSpace(1)),
                    GridView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      primary: false,
                      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 7,childAspectRatio: .5
                      ),
                      itemCount: 42,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        int day = (index+2)- firstDate.weekday;
                        DateTime date = DateTime(2023,month+1,day);
                        if(day>0 && day<=lastDay){
                          return Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey), // Add borders
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                const Align(
                                  alignment:Alignment.topRight,
                                  child: CircleAvatar(
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                      radius: 3),
                                ),
                                CustomText('$day'),
                              ],
                            ), // Display day number
                          );
                        }
                        return const SizedBox();

                      },
                    )
              ]);
            },
          ),
```

Tip:Consider start & end dates by initialising these:
`DateTime start = DateTime(2023,09,1); DateTime end = DateTime(2023,09,10);`
[image: UI which needs to be implemented on code]